# Which is better - execute(INSERT) or executemany(INSERT)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pysqlite

Situation: Need to insert quite a bit of data into a SQLite database.

Problem: There are two statements we can use to insert data -

```
data = [("111", "222", "333"), ("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), ("XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ")]

#method1
for item in data:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table(value1, value2, value3) VALUES (?,?,?)", item)
    conn.commit()

#method2
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table(value1, value2, value3) VALUES(?,?,?)", data)
conn.commit()
```

Question: If ignoring speeds, which one is better practice from a programming point of view? And if possible, explain why as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From purely programming practice point of view, aside from speed, there is no difference. However...

Prepared statements are good. However, mass-insert makes a mass of variable bindings, and SQLite has an [upper limit](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_variable_number) to number of host parameters it can process, which defaults to 999.

Thus, multi-insert is nice for toying around, but for real data you'll be using a loop. One good advice I can offer though is you'll want to wrap the loop in a transaction, because without it, AFAIK, each insert will be an automatic transaction, which will drastically impact the time. (Also, commit at the end of the loop, not within the loop.)

EDIT: According to Python docs,

> By default, the sqlite3 module opens transactions implicitly before a Data Modification Language (DML) statement (i.e. `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`/`REPLACE`), and commits transactions implicitly before a non-DML, non-query statement (i. e. anything other than `SELECT` or the aforementioned).

So your code in #method1 is doing [`BEGIN`], `INSERT`, `COMMIT`, [`BEGIN`], `INSERT`, `COMMIT`... with `BEGIN` implicitly being sent by Python to start a transaction, and `COMMIT` explicitly ending it. If you structure your code like this:

```
for item in data:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table(value1, value2, value3) VALUES (?,?,?)", item)
conn.commit()
```

then you have one implicit `BEGIN` at the start, lots of `INSERTS` and one explicit `COMMIT` at the end. This should speed up your code by 10-20x or so.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further on what you mean by "wrap the loop in a transaction"?